# SQL Explain Plan Tuning

Tags: sql, performance

Simple SQL below would return 1 record, and executed quite fast.
It also has good explain plan (using P1 index which is primary key indexes).

The only problem is it needs Huge buffer i.e. bytes = 347 million (below is copied from the plan).

```
6 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT Cost: 2  Bytes: 347,432,257  Cardinality: 9,390,061
```

Table S_ORG_EXT and S_OPTY is having HUGE volume. It is something that i could not control.
Do you have any idea how to optimize the plan to use lower size of buffer?

Thanks in advance!

SQL:

```
SELECT A1.NAME
  FROM SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT A1, SIEBEL.S_OPTY A3, SIEBEL.S_BU A4
 WHERE     A1.ROW_ID = A3.PR_DEPT_OU_ID                                    --4
       AND A3.ROW_ID = :V1                                                 --1
       AND A4.ROW_ID = A3.BU_ID                                            --2
       AND A3.PR_DEPT_OU_ID IS NOT NULL                                    --3
```

Plan

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 5  Bytes: 77  Cardinality: 1                
    7 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 5  Bytes: 77  Cardinality: 1              
        4 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 3  Bytes: 40  Cardinality: 1          
            2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_OPTY Cost: 3  Bytes: 31  Cardinality: 1    
                1 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_OPTY_P1 Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1  
            3 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_BU_P1 Cost: 0  Bytes: 1,485  Cardinality: 165   
        6 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT Cost: 2  Bytes: 347,432,257  Cardinality: 9,390,061        
            5 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT_P1 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to optimize the plan, as you already know the sql runs fast and the bytes is an estimate of how many bytes are returned by the row source.
Nested Loops is not the most efficient for very larg tables, som depending on size of other tables you could strive for hash joins with use_hash hint or setting optimizer_index_caching ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams143.htm )